# Involuntary vs Passive, Voluntary vs Active?

Tags: word-choice, difference

I was wondering what differences are between involuntary and passive,  and voluntary and active?

For example, a program can directly call a function to do something, or it can receive a request from another process and the request handler calls the same function to do the same thing. Would the action in the first case be called voluntary or active, and the action in the second involuntary or passive?

Thanks.

Comment: You have these concepts organized strangely.  Conventional pairings are *direct vs indirect*, *voluntary vs involuntary* and *active vs passive*.

Comment: you misunderstood me. I am asking difference between involuntary and passive, between voluntary and active.

Comment: There is no necessary difference.  There is no necessary similarity.  They have no bearing on each other.  They don't make reasonable pairs.  Also, they don't have any obvious bearing on your unclear use case.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a connection here. Voluntary and involuntary can both be applied to active, similarly voluntary and involuntary can both be applied to passive, for example:

- Involuntary passive - If someone waits for their knee to be gently tapped with a hammer (passively waiting), this causes an involuntary reaction, the knee jerks up
- Voluntary passive - If someone is slapped (passive), then they have the choice to respond, then choice to respond is voluntary
- Involuntary active - If someone goes to a horror movie, they have actively attended the event and they might scream involuntarily as a reaction.
- Voluntary active - If someone is angry they may actively pick a fight, they may actively look for trouble and then choose to participate (voluntarily hit someone).

For computers, the word "voluntary" is not really applicable.  The client server model would have the client as active and the server as passive, but any response in a computer is "automatic".  The word voluntary implies choice, the computer doesn't sit there and think "hmm, I quite like this client and so will respond to the request".  So I would therefore describe it as automatic passive or active.

[Active and passive adjectives](http://www.alumni.org.br/Quiz/Faq/act.html): Additionally, active and passive can be used to describe adjectives, where active adjectives, ending in –ing, express the idea that someone or something causes a certain effect. Passive adjectives, which end in –ed, express that someone or something experiences this effect.